# How can i render angular application server side and embedd in another angular application?

Tags: java, angular, renderer

So I am working on a application where you can easily create forms. 
The application is in Angular 8.

When a application creates a form it stores a jsonfile with the form structure, later on i can access my backend and see the full angular form with styling and everything.

When the request is sended to my backend, my backend uses a renderer (basically the angular application) and responds with a complete page. It takes the Json file and runs on the renderer and replies with a page.

Here is my question, is it possible to include that page in another angular application? The way i can access it is through a link so a possible solution is a iframe but that does not solve my problem. I want the page to simply open the other application withing itself.

Maybe if i can build the page somehow on my backend and send a complete page, i have been searching around and found out that there is Angular elements where i can embedd one application into other. But i am not completely sure that will do the trick, since there are multiple versions of the application.

Any help or ideas would help me alot.

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: I am sorry, have not been posting on a long time. Changed the question, thank you.

Comment: From what I understand, I would create a component which will be reused anywhere you want and then integrate that component in each target page you wish to use it.

Comment: Yes, that is possible if you are working on the same application. This is not a component, i have a fully completed application that renders a page based on the json file. Now what i want to do is have another application to open that page without using iframe. Imagine if i send a request to a server and the page just opens on the application when the response is ready.